# How to make LoadLibrary to show error dialog when there are missing dependencies

Tags: c, winapi, dll, windows-10, loadlibrary

Suppose we have two dynamic libraries `libfoo.dll` and `libbar.dll`, given that `libbar.dll` depends on `libfoo.dll`. Further we compile an executable `test.exe` that loads our `libbar.dll` using WinAPI function `LoadLibrary()`.

If we run `text.exe` on Windows XP with missing `libfoo.dll`, `LoadLibrary()` shows dialog box alerting than `libfoo.dll` is actually missing and sets `LastError` to `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` (126).

If we run same `text.exe` in same conditions on Windows 10, `LoadLibrary()` sets `LastError` to `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` only, no dialog box appears.

In both cases `ErrorMode` is 0. So is there any possibility to catch a name of missing dependency in `LoadLibrary()` calling process, or, at least, how to make  `LoadLibrary()` show error dialog on Windows 10?

Here is a sample code (using MinGW):

### foo.c

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Compile with: `gcc foo.c -o libfoo.dll -fPIC -shared`

### bar.c

```
int foo(int a, int b);

int bar(int a, int b)
{
    return foo(a, b);
}
```

Compile with: `gcc bar.c -o libbar.dll -fPIC -shared -L. -lfoo`

### test.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*pfn)(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    SetErrorMode(0);

    HMODULE hmod = LoadLibrary("libbar.dll");

    if(!hmod)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error loading library %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    pfn bar = (pfn)GetProcAddress(hmod, "bar");
    if(bar)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "bar(3, 1) = %d\n", bar(3, 1));
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't load bar foonction\n");
    }

    FreeLibrary(hmod);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with: `gcc test.c -o test`

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with default mode of [`SetErrorMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Quote from LoadLibary function docu: To enable or disable error messages displayed by the loader during DLL loads, use the SetErrorMode function.

Comment: As I mentioned above my ErrorMode is set to 0 (SetErrorMode(0) in test.c sample), which means (according to msdn doc) it should show all dialogs.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: xp call `NtRaiseHardError` if depended dll fail to load. as result you and can view error dialog and `SetErrorMode` have effect. but win10 not call `NtRaiseHardError` more. as result no error dialog and error mode not play role here

Comment: To David Heffernan: well, we have a bunch of legacy code (compiled in MSVS 2003 for winXP) which shows such dialogs, and we want to save that behaviour on Win10, it's important for us to know excactly what library is missing.
To RbMm: thanks for that explanation. But is there are any options?

Comment: There is something wrong if you are relying on that old legacy behaviour. You weren't meant to use it on xp either. Find a better solution to the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I totally agree that I shouldn't rely on it and it's acceptable to use some other solution.

Comment: As an option, i could explicitly check libbar.dll dependencies (with LoadLibrary()). In my case, I know what libraries shoud be checked. But maybe there is a way to get .dll dependencies in code?

Comment: Why do you need to check anything? Just install the right DLLs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, recent case: the client messed up with the distro we provide and some libraries were lost - those on which the others depend. In that case for both client and developer it seems like there is a problem with `LoadLibrary()` target  as it produces 126 error. So it would be nice to be able to determine that the actual problem is missing dependencies.

Comment: You need a better install program. That's the real problem.  ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND is the right error code. Handle it properly.

Comment: I suppose you could enable [delay-loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls) for *libbar.dll*. That way you'll get callbacks for every module it tries to load. You don't have to manually check for a list of dependencies, that might change over time. I'm not sure that this option is available in Visual Studio 2003, though.

Comment: You could include a utility program for a user to run that prints debug strings from your application in a simple loop that basically calls `WaitForDebugEventEx`, `ReadProcessMemory`, `ContinueDebugEvent`. With loader snaps (0x2) enabled in the executable's "Image File Execution Options" subkey "GlobalFlag" value, the loader is very chatty. Just look for a line like `LdrpProcessWork - ERROR: Unable to load DLL: "foo.dll", Parent Module: "C:\Temp\bar.dll", Status: 0xc0000135`. That's the native status code `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, i'll try these options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it seems like there is no elegant solution to the question posed.

As @DavidHeffernan noted in the comments to the original post, the problem should be solved on a fundamentally different level. As `LoadLibrary()` behaves just like it should behave, the key is the proper installation and error handling.

However, if the one needs to explicitly catch missing dependencies of the dynamically loaded libraries, the techniques provided by @IInspectable and @eryksun could be applied:

- enabling [Delay-Loded DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) for the libraries that are going to be dynamically loaded. Such an approach provides helper callbacks for each dependent module, so missing dependencies could be handled in place. The main disadvantage of this approach is that the target library should be recompiled with proper linker flags;
- the helper utility that dumps debug strings from the application could be written (see @eryksun comment to the original post for details). Disadvantages: besides the need of writing an additional module it also includes some registry manipulations.