# Is there a way to get the DLL Loader to inform me of missing DLLs?

Tags: c++, winapi

This question has plagued me for years. Not strong enough to do anything real about it. Just a small thorn in one's side.

Why is it that if you start a program and have a missing DLL, you get a nice informative message telling you which DLL is missing? Yet, when you use `::LoadLibrary` you just get a `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`.

Raymond Chen explains this a bit further [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131127-00/?p=2553). To me this answers why there's a dialog box, and not an error code. But it doesn't explain the burning question -- "How can I know *which* DLL is missing?"

I'm aware that I could build this, similar to Dependency Walker. However, in order to do this you have to properly match the DLL search path order.

Is anyone aware of an easy way to get the loader to tell me what it couldn't find? I don't want the dialog, I just want the missing dependency.

**Similar thread:**

[How to make LoadLibrary to show error dialog when there are missing dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120993/how-to-make-loadlibrary-to-show-error-dialog-when-there-are-missing-dependencies)

Comment: There is no API to allow the loader to tell you *which* DLL failed to load.

Comment: The linked topics point to loader snaps and delay loading. Don't know that you'll find better ways than that.

Comment: Thanks. @RemyLebeau do you happen to know how the loader does it when it's standing up the executable? I feel like there has to be a function call somewhere?

Comment: @mvpete the loader parses the executable's PE header, loading each dependent DLL, parsing their PE headers and loading their dependent DLLs, recursively. So, why do you think the loader wouldn't know which DLLs are missing? It is the one loading them. It just doesn't expose details about that logic to the caller

Comment: @RemyLebeau, sorry for the confusion. I would expect that it does know which one it couldn't load. I'm just trying to find out if it's possible to somehow access that. As opposed to walking the PE myself. Because the search path traversal matters, and I think it would be hard to get right.

Comment: You can use `Profile` feature of the Dependency Walker (https://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/application_profiling.htm), that will tell you which library was not found when you do `::LoadLibrary`, I believe. Or are you trying to inform your user at run time?

Comment: Yeah. Ideally I'd like to inform the user.

Comment: Have you tried the [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160) provided in the linked topic?

Comment: I haven’t yet. Though, I’m not sure delay loading is what I need? Because they could be DLLs I haven’t compiled myself.